# parquet4s not returning all records

Tags: scala, hadoop, parquet, cats-effect, fs2

I have a simple Scala application that uses parquet4s with fs2 to read a set of partitioned records (spread across directories, generated by a Spark job).

When I run the app, it only returns a fraction of the records from the partitioned directories. There are no errors ... it just stops after a specific number.

The console output has no useful information:

```
2022-04-07 18:32:29,231 |-INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader [io-compute-4] RecordReader initialized will read a total of 83 records.
2022-04-07 18:32:29,231 |-INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader [io-compute-4] at row 0. reading next block
2022-04-07 18:32:29,231 |-INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader [io-compute-4] block read in memory in 0 ms. row count = 83
```

An equivalent app written using pyArrow in Python is able to retrieve all records.

Any help in debugging this issue is appreciated.

Thank you.

PS - For reference, this is the sample program I use:
https://mjakubowski84.github.io/parquet4s/docs/partitioning/

Comment: I see the same behavior when I switch to using Akka (instead of fs2). Furthermore, I see the same behavior with the partitioned directories on a regular filesystem or AWS S3.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like names of directories containing the partitioned data had characters that are not admissible, causing the reader to skip them, thereby returning fewer records.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).